# React - Syntaxerror: unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, pg

I'd like to use Express, pg and react for my project. But react give me some problems.

[Here's my project's dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmrx6.png)

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var path = require('path');
var app = require('./app/app.js');

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server is running on port 3000!");
});

var connexionDB = require('./db/connexionAvecPg');
```

app.js

```
var react = require('react');
var {render} = require('react-dom');

var App = react.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return(
                <div>
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
                );
    }
});

render(
        <App/>,
        document.getElementById('root')
        );
```

(Yes it's ES5, but i have my reason for using it instead of ES6-7)

[Here's my bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVPcR.png)

What's wrong with my code? did i forget something?
Thx for your time.

---\ EDIT /---

After Ming Soon's answer, I tried this:

app.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class App extends React.component{
    render() {
        return React.createElement('div', null, 'Test');
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(App, null),
        document.getElementById('root')
        );
```

But i have this:

```
/home/josue/im-expressandpg/app/app.js:14
class App extends React.component{
                       ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

---\ EDIT 2 /---

Thx to PSo i saw my mistake. I changed this:

```
class App extends React.component{
```

To this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
```

When i exec:

```
/home/josue/im-expressandpg/app/app.js:17
        document.getElementById('root')
        ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

If i add this:

```
var document = require('./../public/index.html');
```

I get:

```
/home/josue/im-expressandpg/public/index.html:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <!doctype html>
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: use capital letter C for :React.Component

Answer (score 1):

To use the JSX syntax, you have to transpile the code. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) can be used as a transpiler. If you don't want to use any transpiler, then you should use `react.createElement()` function.

Comment: I did few modifications, can you see with me?

Comment: Without ES6, use `react.createClass` to define a component as you did at first. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lower part of the code, that's duplicate of render function. And remember to export it for later use.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class App extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return React.createElement('div', null, 'Test');
    }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: But I want only one React file (for the moment). I have to ReactDOM.render it somewhere, right?
thx for your help.